# Network not found

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

When running `docker-compose` *sometimes* I get error about non-existing default network. According to logs it's created at the beginning

Example of logs:

```
$ docker-compose up -d

Creating network "example_default" with the default driver
Pulling someimage <...>
1.2.3: Pulling from someimage
Digest: sha256: <...>
Status: Downloaded newer image for <...>
Creating sample_1 ... 
Creating example_redis_1                 ... 
Creating example_someimage_1    ... error
ERROR: for example_someimage_1  Cannot start service someimage: network example_default not found
```

It feels that it happens when pulling takes a lot of time.

What is possible reason of this behaviour? How can I debug and fix it?

Comment: Can you share your docker-compose.yml?

Answer (score 0):

You can try use `network_mode: bridge` and write links between containers inside your docker-compose.yml
Then docker-compose will use docker0 bridge and will not create new networks . 
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3899